# Getting error while remove docker image_id

Tags: docker

```
docker images -a 
REPOSITORY          TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
node                test                337b7fc90dbc        2 hours ago         301.8 MB
<none>              <none>              60d47994bba8        2 hours ago         301.8 MB
<none>              <none>              987deffef7bf        2 hours ago         196.7 MB
docker.io/centos    centos7             970633036444        4 weeks ago         196.7 MB



docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                      PORTS               NAMES
774f0d06ec9a        970633036444        "bash"              2 hours ago         Exited (1) 30 minutes ago                       elated_cray
b1f9481f6eae        337b7fc90dbc        "bash"              2 hours ago         Exited (0) 30 minutes ago                       serene_stallman
```

But,when I run `docker rmi 987deffef7bf`,get the error

```
Failed to remove image (987deffef7bf): Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to delete 987deffef7bf (cannot be forced) - image has dependent child images
```

Answer (score 0):

This indicates that another image, most likely "node" from the timestamp is using that image as part of it's layers. This is the design of how images are created from layers and the `docker images -a` exposes some of those workings to the end user. If you remove the "node" image, these should automatically get cleaned.

Answer (score 0):

Just run `docker rmi -f 987deffef7bf`, to force it anyway. Or, delete the child images then delete it afterwards.